# Displaying URL inside table td - Pug/Jade - currently only displaying as text

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the following Pug snippet and I'm trying to show a URL inside one of the `td` tags. However, when I run this the resulting output is displaying `a(href=val.url+'/update')` followed by the correct `#{val.name}`. How do I go about telling Pug that the value inside the `td` tag is a link and that `#{val.name}` should be the hyperlink? If I remove the table and display the `href` tag inside a `p` tag it works fine.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title

  table.table.table-condensed
    thead
      tr
        th Name
        th Date Created
        th Date Modified
        th Ready for Hire
      tbody
      each val in list_genres
        tr
          td a(href=val.url+'/update') #{val.name}
          td #{val.date_created}
          td #{val.date_created}
          td No
      else
        li There are no candidates.
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the `a`-element on a new line below, with an extra indent? AFAIK, Pug interprets any code that directly follows a tag on the same line as text.

Comment: Brilliant! That makes sense now that I've seen `p` tags written with text on the new line.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @gandreadis, the solution is below. Any text seen after recognized code (in this case `td`) is interpreted as text only. A new line is needed.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title

  table.table.table-condensed
    thead
      tr
        th Name
        th Date Created
        th Date Modified
        th Ready for Hire
      tbody
      each val in list_genres
        tr
          td 
            a(href=val.url+'/update') #{val.name}
          td #{val.date_created}
          td #{val.date_created}
          td No
      else
        li There are no candidates.
```